# Is a smooth function sending algebraic numbers to algebraic numbers a polynomial?

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-number-theory

In other words if $f:\mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ is an entire function such that $$f(\overline{\mathbb{Q}}) \subset \overline{\mathbb{Q}}$$
where $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ is the field of algebraic numbers. Can we say that it is a polynomial?

A similar question (though I'm not sure if it is the same question): Let $g$ be a meromorphic function such that $g:\mathbb{\overline{\mathbb{Q}}} \to \overline{\mathbb{Q}}\cup \{\infty\}$; can we say it is a rational function?

Comment: What about this http://mathoverflow.net/a/78527 ?

Comment: Uau! thanks for the link, I'm very impressed, I didn't expect the answer to be negative and even less that a function could exist sending every number field to itself!

Comment: "Smooth" should be changed to "analytic" in the title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a CW answer to remove this question from the unanswered list -- this question has been answered on [Mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/78526/maps-preserving-algebraic-numbers/78527#78527). The answer is no; see [this paper](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/journal-of-the-australian-mathematical-society/article/transcendental-entire-functions-mapping-every-algebraic-number-field-into-itself/DF5DA800386B77C90CE8C3D6BBB5C71D).